Create a boolean column SQL
I would like to know how to create a boolean column notifying that this id exists between the tables.
example: if this ID is only table 1, true as table_1, false as table_2, false table_3.
If this ID is on table 1 and table 2, true as table_1, true as table_2, false table_3.
EXAMPLE:
select 
case when a.id is not null or b.id is not null or c.id then True else False end as table_1,
case when a.id is not null or b.id is not null or c.id then True else False end as table_2
from table
left join table_2 using (id)
left join table_3 using (id)


You can find out if an ID shows up in different tables and make boolean columns for each table. This involves using LEFT JOIN along with CASE statements. Let's walk through an example that matches what you're looking for:
so lets say you have T_1, T_2, T_3, all have column id. To generate a result set having the boolean columns which indicate whether or not those ids are present in each table.
SELECT 
    t1.id,
    CASE WHEN t1.id IS NOT NULL THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS T_1,
    CASE WHEN t2.id IS NOT NULL THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS T_2,
    CASE WHEN t3.id IS NOT NULL THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS T_3
FROM T_1 t1
LEFT JOIN T_2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN T_3 t3 ON t1.id = t3.id;

